# How can I figure out what the <disk> argument should be for this proxmox resize command?

Tags: virtual-machine, disk-usage, proxmox

Forgive me as my knowledge of unix/linux and virtual machines is very limited. I ran the following command recently in a virtual machine managed by Proxmox:

```
[~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop3       59G   56G     0 100% /
none            492K  4.0K  488K   1% /dev
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/tty
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G  800M  7.1G  10% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           410M     0  410M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           410M     0  410M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           410M     0  410M   0% /run/user/1002
```

As you can see `/dev/loop3` is full and I wanted to increase the size of it. The output of the `mount` command shows this is an ext4 filesystem. Looking at [the documentation](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/qm.1.html), there is a resize command:

`qm resize <vmid> <disk> <size> [OPTIONS]`

I'm trying to figure out what I need to use for the `<disk>` argument. According to the docs, it would be any one of the following:

```
<disk>: <efidisk0 | ide0 | ide1 | ide2 | ide3 | sata0 | sata1 | sata2 | sata3 | sata4 | sata5 | scsi0 | scsi1 | scsi10 | scsi11 | scsi12 | scsi13 | scsi14 | scsi15 | scsi16 | scsi17 | scsi18 | scsi19 | scsi2 | scsi20 | scsi21 | scsi22 | scsi23 | scsi24 | scsi25 | scsi26 | scsi27 | scsi28 | scsi29 | scsi3 | scsi30 | scsi4 | scsi5 | scsi6 | scsi7 | scsi8 | scsi9 | tpmstate0 | virtio0 | virtio1 | virtio10 | virtio11 | virtio12 | virtio13 | virtio14 | virtio15 | virtio2 | virtio3 | virtio4 | virtio5 | virtio6 | virtio7 | virtio8 | virtio9>
```

I was able to login to the web interface for Proxmox and resize the disk through the GUI, which produced the following output:

```
()
Image resized.
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/loop3 is mounted on /tmp; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 8, new_desc_blocks = 10
The filesystem on /dev/loop3 is now 20971520 (4k) blocks long.

TASK OK
```

This fixed the issue, but I'd like to know how I can utilize the `qm resize <disk>` command to do the same thing.

Comment: There's very little that can't be done via the Proxmox GUI. You should start by familiarising yourself with the management operations available to you. Among other things you'll see disk storage for the host and whether this VM is fully virtualised or is a container

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Timothy, please remove the Edit and Update sections. Just edit the main question, so it doesn't get to long and confusing. If you solved the problem, it's best you post an answer to the question and select it as the solution. Other people will instantly see there is a solution already and can still suggest other solutions if they think they know a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes thanks everyone. I updated the question. The issue has been technically solved but I'd still like to know how I could utilize the terminal command.